# Unexpected symmetry of wave equations in momentum representation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, fourier-transform, lorentz-symmetry, klein-gordon-equation

In the $x$-representation, the translational invariance implies that
$$
\mathcal{D}[\psi(\vec{x},t)]=0\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \mathcal{D}[\operatorname{e}^{i\vec{a}\hat{\vec{P}}}\psi(\vec{x},t)]=0
$$
where $\hat{\vec{P}} = -i\nabla$ and $\mathcal{D}$ is the differential operator corresponding to some translationally-invariant equation. Let's explore how this works in the momentum representation. For definiteness, let's use the KG equation. After the Fourier transform, it reads as
$$
\left[\partial^2_t+(\vec{p}^2+m^2)\right]\psi(\vec{p},t)=0
$$
Since in this representation $\hat{\vec{P}} = \vec{p}\cdot$, we have:
$$
\operatorname{e}^{i\vec{a}\hat{\vec{P}}}\psi(\vec{p},t) = \operatorname{e}^{i\vec{a}\vec{p}}\psi(\vec{p},t)
$$
Consequently,
$$
\left[\partial^2_t+(\vec{p}^2+m^2)\right]\left(\operatorname{e}^{i\vec{a}\vec{p}}\psi(\vec{p},t)\right)
=\operatorname{e}^{i\vec{a}\vec{p}}\left[\partial^2_t+(\vec{p}^2+m^2)\right]\psi(\vec{p},t)
=0
$$
So, if $\psi(\vec{p},t)$ is a solution, then $\operatorname{e}^{i\vec{a}\vec{p}}\psi(\vec{p},t)$ is a solution as well.

However, by looking at the last equation, we conclude that we can actually multiply $\psi(\vec{p},t)$ by an arbitrary function of $\vec{p}$, and it still will be a solution:
$$
\left[\partial^2_t+(\vec{p}^2+m^2)\right]\left(f(\vec{p})\psi(\vec{p},t)\right)
=f(\vec{p})\left[\partial^2_t+(\vec{p}^2+m^2)\right]\psi(\vec{p},t)
=0
$$

Here comes the question: if $f(\vec{p})\psi(\vec{p},t)$ is always a solution, why it is only the operator of multiplying by $\vec{p}$ who generates symmetries? Naively, I would expect some infinite-dimensional Lie algebra to emerge.

I would like to have an answer not relying on Fourier-transforming back to the position space but rather at the level of the equation in the momentum space.

Comment: You seem to have rediscovered that a superposition of plane waves, say, is  still a solution of the wave equation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see how this discovery provides an immediate answer to my question.

Comment: Consider $\phi(x)=\int\!\mathrm{d}^4p\,a(p)\,\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} p\cdot x}+\text{cc}$, where $p\cdot x=Et-\vec p\cdot \vec x$.

Comment: I am aware of the that the linear combination of plane waves, which you just wrote, is the general form of the solution of the plane wave equation. But what is the algebra of operators generating the general $\psi(\vec{p},t)\rightarrow f(\vec{p})\psi(\vec{p},t)$ transformation?

Comment: What is your reasoning for conclusion that one can multiply by an arbitrary function of $\vec{p}$?

Comment: The vanishing commutator ${\left[\partial^2_t+(\vec{p}^2+m^2),\,f(\vec{p})\right]}$.

Comment: There is no nontrivial algebra involved other than $0\cdot f(\vec p)=0$. The function $a$ in my mode expansion above is more or less what you call $f$.

Comment: Indeed, you do get an infinite-dimensional algebra. You've rediscovered [BMS supertranslations](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.532782). Congrats!